# Multiplied query results

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I have a query to extract invoices from a shipping table. The query contains functions such as `SUM(salprc*qty)` and joined tables.

Today I have a client with 3 invoices whose numbers are tripled. However, I have a client with 2 invoices whose numbers are correct. I checked the data, the joined tables, made sure my client is not listed multiple times, and compared the data of the 3  invoices with the data of the 2 invoices. I cannot understand why this is happening.

I must be overlooking something obvious but it escapes me. 
Any suggestion would be welcome.
/bja

Comment: You might need to do your aggregation in a subquery and then join to it.  You'd need to post your table structure, sample data and desired results to know for sure though.

Comment: Posting the query would be the next step - without being able to see the code, any advice offered would be a guess.

Comment: The plot thickens: when I run my query and its subqueries in a separate program, I get the correct results. When it's part of my form I get the error above...

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I have just noticed that the Data Environment of my form was pointing to the wrong table, where the client was indeed listed 3 times. Now I have to figure out why it was listed 3 times...

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't do sum() on joined tables. It would only work right, when the joined table is a 'parent' one.